# Crashed on check Navigation bar

Tags: android, navigation

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  TextView tv;

private Context context;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
    boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
    boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

    if (!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey && !hasHomeKey) {
        tv.setText("Has Present");
    } else {
        tv.setText("Has Not!");
    }
   }
   }
```

I am trying to check if device has a navbar or not on some devices there are both nav bar + hard key "one plus one" and other that's run on custom rom so I tried to check if navbar is available or not

But it crashed on checking what should i do

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: 01-08 09:51:31.138 D/dalvikvm(26274): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-08 09:51:31.198 I/dalvikvm(26274): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
01-08 09:51:31.428 D/AndroidRuntime(26274): Shutting down VM
01-08 09:51:31.428 W/dalvikvm(26274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4196bba8)
01-08 09:51:31.433 E/AndroidRuntime(26274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 09:51:31.433 E/AndroidRuntime(26274): Process: com.showNavigationBar, PID: 26274
01-08 09:51:31.433 E/AndroidRuntime(26274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sh

Comment: Can you please post your layout xml for the main activity class?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
  android:id="@+id/mainTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>